# How to create tag type of label in Cad Eagle?

Tags: schematics, eaglecad, cad

I can't get my copy of cad eagle to create tag type of label for a wire or a net. Instead I get simple text type of label. GND label is what I am trying to get.

[image]

I have tried turning xref on and off, and changing size or font. In the end, all I get is simple plain text label. So, how do I get the fancy tag type of label?

Comment: See [this answer](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/104579/30062).

Comment: @David That is exactly what I am doing. I have selected the pretty arrow, same size, ratio, and font, yet I get simple text label.

Comment: Then you are either doing it wrong or you've found a bug.  Ensure you are choosing the options from the linked post.  If you are, record your steps (video or screenshots) and report it to Cadsoft.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zMHEg9M8FWA Then I suppose it is a bug or an issue with my installation of software.

Comment: Yes - looks like it to me.  Report it to Cadsoft.

Answer (score 2):

You can make it as a component with the value inside the tag box.

What about this?

[image]

But remember that if you want to have similar pins (on the same net) connected, you must use the `Name` command for every particular net segment! Placing this `component` on a wire doesn't tell EAGLE to connect those wires!

Comment: Is there a way to bind this nice tag component with default label command? For example, below is link to video showing just that. http://youtu.be/6ikZHzEYQcQ?t=24s

Comment: Well actually that is the correct way of doing it. I didn't know of that feature of EAGLE.

Comment: Yes, but that feature does not seem to work for me. I pointed this out on comment to the question, I have tried adding the label with exactly same options selected. As a result, it ends up being simple text label nonetheless.

Comment: This requires a footprint right?  A device needs a symbol and a footprint.  Nets have names and not values.  So I am totally confused with your approach.  Can you please elaborate?